Identify this hollywood movie where a movie director makes a film based on a student's story
Nearly 5 years ago I watched Hollywood movie (I think in HBO/starmovies).
This story is about a lazy student (looks like he's in the 5/6th standard) who didn't do any homework. So one day the principal / a teacher gave a warning that if he didn't write a story for the next day he will expelled or something.
So this kid worked hard, stayed up late and wrote an awesome story. On next morning while going to school on his bicycle, he was in a small car accident with a movie director (who didn't have any stories and was in bad position). Then the movie director gave the kid a lift to school. But the twist is that kid forgets his story in the director's car. The director read that story and made a film about it. What happened then?
What movie was this?

I think you're talking about Big Fat Liar from 2002 with Frankie Muniz and Paul Giamatti. From Wiki:

After [14 year old] Jason fails to complete a creative writing assignment for class his teacher gives him a day to write it... Jason writes a story entitled Big Fat Liar... On his way to school Jason has a run in with arrogant Hollywood producer Marty Wolf... whom he convinces to give him a ride... Jason accidentally forgets his report in Wolf's limousine. Wolf initially attempts to give it back to Jason, but when he sees that it is excellent, he decides to keep it for himself.

Here's the trailer.

Thanks Andrew. Out of interest, 'Gentlemen Broncos' from 2009 has a similar theme.
